# Fix a link width after text wrap

Tags: html, css

I have a link with a border that looks like a button and it has the text 'Bezpłatna konsultacja'. This button is too wide for some mobile devices and sometimes wraps into two lines. However, even after wrapping, the link's width occupies 100% of the available space. How can I fix this?

I tried using different 'display' options, and only 'inline' works, but then the border breaks.[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofKV2.png)

Comment: try this on last element `display: inline-block, white-space: nowrap, width: auto, and max-width: 100%`

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work... [New](https://freeimage.host/i/JuBAbLl)